# Execute click on button when mouse if out of button area

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I get button from page which can be clicked only when mouse is on it.

The button looks like :

```
<button class="btn-large red" data-bind="text: submitLabel, trueClick: submit,
          css: { 'light-skin': ff.DealTicket.useLightSkin, disabled: !isValid() || isOrderPending() ||isSubmitting(), blue: isBuy(), red: !isBuy(), yellow: isOCO() }">Place Sell Trade</button>
```

I want execute click on this button, so in console of Developer Tool (Google Chrome browser) I write code like :

```
document.querySelector('button.btn-large.red').click;
```

When I entered code it return only "undefined" and nothing happens. When I put this in interval like:

```
setInterval(function(){
    document.querySelector('button.btn-large.red').click();
    }, 2000)
```

It should click on button every two seconds but not click. When I put mouse on this button, this code from Interval works and clicked...

I tried also interval with focus on

```
setInterval(function(){
    document.querySelector('button.btn-large.red').focus();
    document.querySelector('button.btn-large.red').click();
    }, 2000)
```

...but is the same, do not click when mouse is away from this button.

What I should do to click on this button with mouse away from this button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be working. 
Why do you say it's not working? Did you add some event listener to the click event on the button?

```js
document.querySelector('button.btn-large.red').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('Clicked');})

document.querySelector('button.btn-large.red').click();


setInterval(function() {
  document.querySelector('button.btn-large.red').focus();
  document.querySelector('button.btn-large.red').click();
}, 2000)
```

```html
<button class="btn-large red" data-bind="text: submitLabel, trueClick: submit,
          css: { 'light-skin': ff.DealTicket.useLightSkin, disabled: !isValid() || isOrderPending() ||isSubmitting(), blue: isBuy(), red: !isBuy(), yellow: isOCO() }">Place Sell Trade</button>
```

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5jr2f1ga/).

Comment: EventListener with 'click' is working but why nothing happens with button ? It means that should do action and do not do this. That is weird.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood. Could you specify what you want to happen when you click on the button?

Comment: There should be something else, click event is fire but button do not react on this event until the mouse is not placed over the button.

Comment: It do not work on page where from I get this button, but on your example it shows that should works but on page - not. Maybe something else should I check on this page ?

Comment: So, is this button inside an iframe?

Comment: no it is not. The button is inside `<div data-bind>...` ---> `<section class ="body">` --> `<div class ="buttons">`